# Magento 2: How to Create Paypal Order Programmatically?

Tags: magento2, orders, custom, paypal, magento2.1.5

I have below link for creating order

https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-create-order-programmatically.html

How can we create Order with Paypal?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you use PayPal Express, you will need to change the following

from

```
$quote->setPaymentMethod('checkmo'); //payment method
```

to

```
$quote->setPaymentMethod('paypal_express'); //payment method
```